# Crystal Syntax Program (Crystal Reports)

Tags: syntax, crystal-reports, syntax-error, syntax-highlighting

I was wondering if anybody knew of any programs out there that allow you to write Crystal Syntax which highlight syntax and error checks. I was going to use Notepad++ to do this, but Crystal is not an option in the languages. It allows you to import, but I am not sure how to import the libraries properly and would just like a program to do Crystal Coding in.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I doubt an external program will be able to check the code for errors. How is it going to get the list of the database fields? What is the problem with Crystal designer editor?

Comment: I was just trying to learn the Crystal Reports Syntax. I thought it might be easier to use a program than to actually go into the Crystal Reports program...Just want to practice and learn the syntax. I have been looking for a program and other helpful websites that might offer these things. I could really use them.

Comment: I would suggest you to use Crystal designer.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a [TextMate bundle for Crystal Reports](https://github.com/craibuc/crystal-reports-tmbundle).  It should also work with Sublime Text.

I also wrote a [source-highlight language definition for the Crystal Report's forumula language](https://github.com/craibuc/source-highlight-crystal).  This will highlight Crystal syntax in AsciiDoc with code blocks:

```
[source,crystal]
----
Function (Stringvar foo)

// do something here

foo;
----
```

I haven't include all of the functions, so feel free to fork the projects and add the missing elements.